# How would I store NSDate in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, ios4, timestamp

In my SQLite database I have a column named `datekey` of type `TIMESTAMP`.

How would i store my `NSDate` object in the database?

From one of my classes I have already converted an `NSString` to appropriate date like this

```
dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:00:00 AM +0000",dateStr];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a Z"];
NSDate *dateToBeReturned = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Now I want to store this "dateToBeReturned" in to the SQLite database.

Please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A timestamp is an integer of seconds since 1970, thus we can use the following method:

```
[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Replace [NSDate date] with your NSDate object.

**Update:**

To clarify, TimeInterval returned by NSDate is of type `Double` so you might want to be careful with the casting as numbers can sometimes behave oddly.

Another thing that I forgot to mention was that this timestamp does not contain timezone information  that could maybe be relevant for your particular application. There are string formats available that do store this using NSDateFormatter, but you could also just add  a separate column containing the timezone information.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now i am in another trouble. When I am trying to match dates. It showing something worong value. I am using this 
NSString *Sql =@"SELECT ZTIMESLOT,ZAGENDA1,ZAGENDA2 FROM tbl_agenda where tbl_agenda.ZDATEKEY=%d";
   NSString *sqlFormated = [NSString stringWithFormat:Sql,date];

Comment: you should use %lu I think, it could also be %f, don't exactly know whether an NSTimeInterval can be a float ( As you can use it for an NSTimer with 0.00333f as time interval )

Comment: @Tariq- iPHONE Programmer NSTimeInterval
Used to specify a time interval, in seconds.

typedef double NSTimeInterval; -- from apple's documentation, so you should use an %f

Comment: But as i can see in my database timestamp value for 26 feb is 1298678400 which is correct but when i am trying to match with above source code then date value become 78756944 which is complete wrong for comparison. i have used both %f and %lu. But its showing wrong value in debugger